# Spring Security - Authenticate Users With Active Directory against LDAP in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, active-directory, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am gettting LDAP authentication error when we configured for LDAP authentication. My property files as below configuration:

```
 ldap.urls=ldap://***.***.local:8389
    ldap.base.dn=dc=test,dc=com
    ldap.user.dn.pattern=(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})(memberof=CN=Group Name,OU=***,OU=****,DC=test,DC=com))
```

While accessing wsdl by passing valid username & password getting below error:

`While accessing wsdl it is asking username & Password. If we provided then it saying that “ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid`

and while starting the application i am able to see below log on console:

```
`org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource - Property 'userDn' not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operation`
```

for SOAP Calls as i have provided some more in SOAPWebServiceConfig.java even not working.

```
//XwsSecurityInterceptor
    @Bean
    public XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor(){
        XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
        //Callback Handler -> SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler
        securityInterceptor.setCallbackHandler(callbackHandler());
        //Security Policy -> securityPolicy.xml
        securityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        return securityInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler() {
        SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler handler = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
        handler.setUsersMap(Collections.singletonMap("user", "password"));
        return handler;
    }

    //Interceptors.add -> XwsSecurityInterceptor
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(securityInterceptor());
    }
```

I am not getting what is the issue here. Can anyone please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

Active-Directory has LDAP compatible protocol but uses some special conventions compared to other ldap directories.
To get those configured right (e.g. append the domain to usernames) use ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider instead of the LdapAuthenticationProvider which will be uses when using the auto-configuration via Properties. Remove or rename "ldap.urls" and the other properties from your application.yml then.

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain.org",
                "ldap://activedirectory-url:389");
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
    }

}
```

Comment: But it's not working for SOAP Calls. Please help me on this.@TomB

Comment: Try leaving away the "(memberof=CN=Group Name,OU=***,OU=****,DC=test,DC=com)" part to see if that helps.